# How to save a file in PHP and save file characteristics to a database conditional on possible failure

Tags: php, database, gd

I am saving a file to a server and I'm saving the filename, user id of the individual who uploaded the file, and various other information about the file to a PostgreSQL database.  I ideally want to structure this in a way that is similar to a database transaction.  That is, one of the following should occur:

1. Save file
2. If successful, save information to database
3. If saving information to database fails, delete file

OR

1. Save information to database
2. If successful, save file
3. If saving file fails, delete information from database

The only problem with this methodology is step 3 may fail--that is, you may be left with a file saved without corresponding information in the database or you may have database information without a corresponding file saved.

What I want to know is if there is a way that you can use either of the two methods above while ensuring step 3 always occurs or occurs with sufficient reliability that I effectively do not have to worry about failure.

Note that I am using a PostgreSQL database and saving an image file using the `imagegif`, `imagejpeg`, and `imagepng` functions from the GD library.

**EDIT**

In response to Jack's solid comments below, I forgot to mention that I am interacting with the DB through an API server, so instead of directly interacting with the DB, I am sending REST requests to the API which in turn interacting with the DB.  What this effectively means is that I can't just put both database interactions into one transaction.

Comment: Code should *always* have the ability to destroy files that it's uploaded and delete rows that it's created (apart from in convoluted circumstances), so why would step 3 fail?

Comment: Filesystem can crash. And database can crash, too. Failure is always immanent and you can not always recover from it.

Comment: If you go the second route, you can always put steps 1 and 3 into a transaction, rolling back if step 2 fails.  If the database goes down before the transaction is committed, then the data won't be saved to the database, however it might be saved to file...but that would be at least as easy to check for than data that was saved into a database but not to file.

Comment: Right.  The idea would be a DB crash or--much more likely--a timeout due to a slow connection.  The file delete issue would arise from the file being temporarily locked because it is being read.  I'm not sure what the probability of these events are--or more importantly--the relative probability of these events which would allow me to determine the best possible approach.

Comment: Great idea, Jack.  However, there may be an issue in that I am interacting with the database through a RESTful framework so instead of being able to make a transaction on the server itself, I have to make two separate API calls, which inherently results in two separate transactions.  (That is, I can't send two request to the API server and have it interact with the DB as one transaction.)  I should have made the use of a RESTful framework clear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to choose a sub-optimal but still workable route of running a periodic check that searches for database entries for every filename and if a database entry cannot be found, then the file is deleted.  (If anyone is actually interested in the code details, I will gladly provide it in an edit.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but maybe like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file(...)){
  if(!mysql_query(...)){
    unlink(...);
  }
}
```

Forgive me, If I couldn't understand or I've been easy going on your question.